# Generate SUM For Foreign Key on one table and append to another in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have been working on this SQL statement for a long time, and I seem not to be progressing..

I have two tables in my database, a loans-request table and a loans-account table, the `loans-request` table stores information about any loan request, while the `loans-account` table stores information about loan repayments, with `RequestId` as  `FK` from the `loans-request` table.

I want to collect all loans request from `loans-request` table and join each with the sum of all payments made for a particular request in `loans-account` table.

I have been battling with this query, I do not know how to go about it.

I tried posting an image of my table, but am unable to because of my reputation

The SQL I Just tried

```
SELECT loans-request.*, SUM(loans-account.Amount) FROM loans-request INNER JOIN loans-account on loans-request.requestId =  loans-account.requestId
```

I would appreciate all help on this thanks, Approximate View of my tables

```
loans-request table
*****************************
RequestId | AmountRequested | Active | Approved | SoftDelete | 
***************************** 

loans-account table
*****************************
AccountId| RequestId | Amount| Active | SoftDelete | 
*****************************
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT lr.RequestId, SUM(la.Amount) AS AmountPaid
FROM LoansRequest lr
INNER JOIN LoansAccounts la
ON lr.RequestId = la.RequestId'
GROUP BY lr.RequestId
```

Comment: wow, i feel dull, thanks a thousand, works just the way i want it, this forum is awesome